# How safely eval() javascript to get indication if it can be evaluated and prevent exceptions?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTQ97/)

```
var a = { prop : 1};
var b = { prop : 2};
var c = { prop : 3};
var d = { prop : 4};
var e = { prop : 5};

var obj = { a : a, b : b, c : c, d : d, e : e, f : 'f stands for fail' };

$(function(){
    console.log('try/catch');
    try{
        for(var p in obj){
            if (typeof p != 'undefined')
                console.log(eval(p));
        }
    }catch(e){}
});

$(function(){
    console.log('check typeof and you will get string');
    for(var p in obj){
        if (typeof p != 'undefined')
            console.log(eval(p));
    }
});
```

Is there a way to check in 'oneliner' (like `typeof p != 'undefined'`) without having to use `try catch` that one would get indication that contents of `eval()` are unevaluatible for whatever reason. Basically to get `true` somehow if it evals without errors and `false` if it fails.

Comment: Including syntax errors?

Comment: You mean `p` is an arbitrary piece of script ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario only variables existing in given scenario, although general solution would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check a code is syntactically valid **without evaluating it** using the `Function` constructor.

```
function isSyntacticallyValid(p){
    try {
        new Function(p);
        return true;
    } catch(e){} // e will typically be a SyntaxError
    return false;
}
```

It's simply impossible in the general case to check in advance the code would really evaluate without error and in finished time (it's an undecidable problem).

**Example :**

```
var codes = [
  "y = x+2", // is OK
  "alert('Hey!')", // this one too
  "random garbage" // but not this one
];

codes.forEach(function(p){
  try {
    new Function(p);
  } catch(e){
    console.log("Bad code : ", p);
  }
});
```